# c++ setter/getter does not work as expected

Tags: c++, list, getter, setter

for some reason my prof insists I have to use setter/getter everywhere.
Well... in this linked list I don't understand why this one doesn't work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class SomeClass{
    string some_string;
public:
    void setSomeString(string s);
    string getSomeString();
};

void SomeClass::setSomeString(string s){
    some_string = s;
}

string SomeClass::getSomeString(){
    return some_string;
}

class Node{
    SomeClass some_class;
    Node *next;
public:
    void setSomeClass(SomeClass sc);
    SomeClass getSomeClass();
    //...
};

void Node::setSomeClass(SomeClass sc){
    some_class = sc;
}

SomeClass Node::getSomeClass(){
    return some_class;
}

class List{
public:
    Node *head, *ptr;
    //...
};

int main(){

    List l;
    l.head = new Node();
    l.head->getSomeClass().setSomeString("a string");

    cout << l.head->getSomeClass().getSomeString();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect in the output "a string", instead is empty... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SomeClass Node::getSomeClass(){...` returns a copy.

Comment: `getSomeClass` returns by value, so modifying it in main doesn't affect the member variable. If you want to modify it, you need to return by reference. Also, I suggest asking your prof *why* they've set this requirement. Having getters and setters that are intended to modify the members seems rather odd, as opposed to just making the members public.

Comment: `Node::getSomeClass()` returns *by value*, which means it returns a *copy* of the object. Once you have modified this copy, it's destructed and the changes are lost.

Comment: you can change the getter to return a reference, but then the presence of the getter is really pointless. Once the caller has a non const reference there is no encapsulation. If your prof pushes you to use setters/getters everywhere you need to ask them why!

Comment: if you ask me, `SomeClass` should be `std::string` and the member `Node::some_class` has to be `public`.

Answer (score 0):

`Node::getSomeClass()` method returns something by value. This means that the returned object is a copy which means that now you have two different objects and there is no side effect.

If you want to edit the original value you need to return it by reference:
`SomeClass& getSomeClass() {...}`

In this way you will get the reference of the original object and you can edit it.

Comment: "...will be destroyed when the current block scope is done." not quite

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't wrap something if wrapper adds nothing to wrapped like `SomeClass` adds nothing to string except useless set/get.
2. Even if `Node::getSomeClass()` returns by reference why it's private in Node? If private member returned by reference it can be abused outside of `Node`.
3. If you insist to make `SomeClass` private in `Node` then `l.head->getSomeClass().setSomeString("a string")` should be `l.head->setSomeString("a string")` where:

   `void Node::setSomeString(string input)`{

   ```
    some_class.setSomeString(input); //while not exposing some_class at all
   ```

   }